# Code looks broken when uploaded vs local host

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When I upload my file from local host to a actual server, the scale seems to be broken.

I've made sure to add DOCTYPE HTML and I've tried to reset the zoom on my browser

code for text:

```css
#greenText{
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 800px;
    margin-top: -320px;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

code for the box:

```css
#green{
    background-color: #C19A6B;
    height: 500px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-right: 300px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;`
     }
```

[Local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGkNA.jpg)

[Uploaded code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFzi5.jpg)

Comment: Code looks broken.... how?

Comment: let's see the HTML  file with the full `<head>` and this box on the page.

Comment: ``border-radius: 50px;` `` backquote

Comment: Looks like an image is missing?

Comment: I dont know the code is broken, but if you look at the images of the site you can see the formating differnece between the two

Comment: Also I know the images are missing, I didnt add them to the file, but the page is still messed up regardless if I put images in.

Comment: Here is all the code:

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how to upload the code, here is the link to the site where it is broken. I apologize for the profanity.

Comment: https://thirstless-interfac.000webhostapp.com/newAbout.html

Comment: try uploading your images

Comment: you also did not add ```<head>``` or ```<body>`` tags in your code

Comment: Update, if I zoom out on chrome to 75% the webpage looks as it should? I don't know what this means, any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you need to move the `newAbout.html` file into the `DJ SUNNOCO/`directory.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried it and the same result as before.

Comment: The images show up, but the problem is that the website looks too zoomed in.